# Apple Music Popup Bar - LNPopupController - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

Im using this framework: https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController and I am trying to make a popup bar on the bottom of the tab bar controller.

It should look like this: 
[image]

but all I am getting is a white box above the tab bar controller.

This is my code, it is what I have been able to pull from the example app when they click a tableviewcell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let popupContentController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlayerViewController") as! PlayerViewController

    popupContentController.popupItem.title = "This is a test"
    popupContentController.popupItem.subtitle = "This is also a test"
    popupContentController.popupItem.image = UIImage(named: "someimage")

    tabBarController?.presentPopupBar(withContentViewController: popupContentController, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I just want it to look like how it does in the above picture.

Cheers

Comment: So it turns out that it was because I had changed the color of the uitabbarcontroller to something other than default.

Comment: Please note that I have recently improved the support for color and tint. You should have a much better experience now.